# Bash menu-driven text file viewer / presenter tool

Tags: parsing, bash

This is a simple Bash script to provide menu driven manuals and standard operating procedures.

Sops and mans with the extension `.sopman.txt` will be loaded.

The file `motd` is required, it is intended to prompt the user with a banner containing useful and or up to date information.

Use the markup `+color+` to colorize a line, see `colors.sopman.txt` for complete list of supported colors.

[Github Project](https://github.com/mattinclude/Bash/tree/master/sopman)

[See Find and Replace Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42740325/bash-variable-search-and-replace-instead-of-sed)

[Powershell Version Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/158147/powershell-menu-driven-text-file-viewer-presenter-tool)

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
#.-----.-----.-----.--------.---.-.-----.
#|__ --|  _  |  _  |        |  _  |     |
#|_____|_____|   __|__|__|__|___._|__|__|
#            |__|   Matthew A. Brassey
version=1.0.0

license="
sopman v${version}
Copyright (C) 2017  Matthew A. Brassey

        This program is free software: you can redistribute it and/or modify
        it under the terms of the GNU General Public License as published by
        the Free Software Foundation, either version 3 of the License, or
        (at your option) any later version.

        This program is distributed in the hope that it will be useful,
        but WITHOUT ANY WARRANTY; without even the implied warranty of
        MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.  See the
        GNU General Public License for more details.

        You should have received a copy of the GNU General Public License
        along with this program.  If not, see <http://www.gnu.org/licenses/>.
"

help="
Usage: ./sopman.sh [--help|--version]

[options]
        --search        Search sopman archive for a string. '--search <search string>'
        --motd          Display message of the day.
        --license       Show lisense information.
"

#Variables
args=("$@")
sops=(sops/*.sopman.txt)
stoploop="false"
endscript="false"
length="${#sops[@]}"

#Colors
lineColor='\e[0m'
reset="\e[0m";
black="\e[1;30m";
blue="\e[1;34m";
cyan="\e[1;36m";
green="\e[1;32m";
purple="\e[1;35m";
red="\e[1;31m";
white="\e[1;37m";
yellow="\e[1;33m";
header="$(echo -e "${cyan}================================================================[sopman]====${reset}")"
footer="$(echo -e "${cyan}============================================================================${reset}")"

#Functions
function search() {
    echo -e "${green}Search results for \"$searchString\":${reset}\n"
    grep -rnw sops/ -e "$searchString" --include "*.sopman.txt"
}

function motd() {
       clear
       echo "$header"
       while read -r line; do
           GETCOLOR "$line"
           newLine=$(echo "$line" | sed "s/+[a-Z]\++//g")
#           shopt -s extglob
#           new_line=${line//(\+)}
           echo -e "${lineColor}${newLine}${reset}"
       done <"motd"
       echo "$footer"
}

function menu0 {
    fcount="0"
    clear
    echo "$header"
    motd
    echo -e "${green}0] Search ${reset}"
    for sop in "${sops[@]}"
    do
        let fcount=fcount+1
        echo -e "${green}$fcount) ${sop:5:-11} ${reset}"
    done
    echo "$footer"
}

function GETCOLOR() {
        if [[ $1 =~ \+[a-Z]+\+? ]]; then
          local match=${BASH_REMATCH[0]};
          case $match in
            "+black+") lineColor=$black;;
            "+red+") lineColor=$red;;
            "+green+") lineColor=$green;;
            "+blue+") lineColor=$blue;;
            "+purple+") lineColor=$purple;;
            "+cyan+") lineColor=$cyan;;
            "+yellow+") lineColor=$yellow;;
            "+white+") lineColor=$white;;
            *) lineColor=$reset;;
          esac
        fi
}

for ((arg=0;arg<"${#args[@]}";arg++)); do
        [ "${args[$arg]}" == "--version" ] && echo "${version}" && exit
        [ "${args[$arg]}" == "--help" ] && echo "${help}" && exit
        [ "${args[$arg]}" == "--license" ] && echo "${license}" && exit
        [ "${args[$arg]}" == "--search" ] && searchString=${args[$arg+1]} && clear && echo "$header" && search && echo "$footer" && exit
        [ "${args[$arg]}" == "--motd" ] && clear && echo "$header" && motd && exit
        #[ "${args[$arg]}" == "--" ] && echo ${args[$arg]}
done

while [ $endscript = "false" ]
do
        menu0 
        while [ $stoploop = "false" ]
        do
                printf "Enter your selection (q to quit) : "
                read -r input1
                if [ "$input1" = "q" ]; then
                echo -e "${cyan}Bye-Bye${reset}"
                exit
                fi
                if [ "$input1" -eq "0" ]; then
                printf "Search for: "
                read -r searchString
                clear
                echo "$header"
                search
                echo "$footer"
                printf "[ 'm' to return to menu, anything else to quit ] : "
                read -r input3
                if [ "$input3" = "m" ]; then
                        break
                else 
                        echo -e "${cyan}Bye-Bye${reset}"
                        exit
                fi
                fi
                if [ "$input1" -ge "1" ] && [ "$input1" -le "$length" ]; then
                        clear
                        echo "$header"
                          while read -r line; do
                            GETCOLOR "$line"
                            newLine=$(echo "$line" | sed "s/+[a-Z]\++//g")
                            echo -e "${lineColor}${newLine}${reset}"
                          done <"${sops[$input1-1]}"
                        echo "$footer"
                        printf "[ 'm' to return to menu, anything else to quit ] : "
                        read -r input2
                        if [ "$input2" = "m" ]; then
                                break
                        else
                                echo -e "${cyan}Bye-Bye${reset}"
                                exit
                        fi
                else
                        echo -e "${red}ERROR! Please select an option : ${reset}"
                        retryCount=$((retryCount+1))
                        if [ "$retryCount" -ge "3" ]; then
                        echo -e "${red}EXIT!${reset}"
                        exit
                        fi
                fi
        done
done
```

Comment: What are you looking for from the code review?

Comment: It would be great to have an answer to the _**[Find and Replace Question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42740325/bash-variable-search-and-replace-instead-of-sed)**_. Also looking for corrections, optimizations & general improvements or suggestions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't have time for a full review, but I'll just mention that you seem to have terminal-specific escapes here:

```
lineColor='\e[0m'
reset="\e[0m";
black="\e[1;30m";
blue="\e[1;34m";
cyan="\e[1;36m";
green="\e[1;32m";
purple="\e[1;35m";
red="\e[1;31m";
white="\e[1;37m";
yellow="\e[1;33m";
```

Assuming these are supposed to be Linux console escapes, they can be more portably written thus:

```
reset="$(tput sgr0)"
lineColor="$reset"
black="$(tput bold; tput setaf 0)"
blue="$(tput bold; tput setaf 4)"
cyan="$(tput bold; tput setaf 6)"
green="$(tput bold; tput setaf 2)"
purple="$(tput bold; tput setaf 5)"
red="$(tput bold; tput setaf 1)"
white="$(tput bold; tput setaf 7)"
yellow="$(tput bold; tput setaf 3)"
```

The above produces real terminal escapes, so you'll be able to drop the non-POSIX `-e` flag to `echo`.  That's a Good Thing, but you will need to properly quote their expansions.

---

In `GETCOLOR`, where these codes are interpolated, there's a very repetitive switch statement:

```
      case $match in
        "+black+") lineColor=$black;;
        "+red+") lineColor=$red;;
        #....
      esac
```

It looks like it would be easier to just substitute the variable name, using `${! }`:

```
function GETCOLOR() {
    if [[ $1 =~ \+[a-Z]+\+? ]]
    then
        local match="${BASH_REMATCH[0]}"
        case "$match" in
            +black+|+red+|+green+|+blue+|+purple+|+cyan+|+yellow+|+white+)
                match="${match//+}"
                lineColor="${!match}"
                ;;
            *)
                lineColor="$reset"
                ;;
        esac
    fi
}
```

That can be simplified further, by using a capture group for the word inside `+...+`:

```
function GETCOLOR() {
    if [[ $1 =~ \+([a-Z]+)\+? ]]
    then
        local match="${BASH_REMATCH[1]}"
        case "$match" in
            black|red|green|blue|purple|cyan|yellow|white)
                lineColor="${!match}"
                ;;
            *)
                lineColor="$reset"
                ;;
        esac
    fi
}
```

Comment: Excellent response. I updated the _**[Github Project](https://github.com/mattinclude/Bash/blob/master/sopman/sopman.sh)**_ per your suggestions.

Comment: I followed your link - there's a few more places where `echo -e` is still used, but the `-e` is no longer needed.  And `"($echo -e something)"` can simplify to `"something"` for `header` and `footer`.